# Publish-Script to Powershell gallery fails

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have PS script which i want to publish to powershell gallery. On trying the command i get the below error. Not sure what to check from here. Any clue ?

```
Command:
Publish-Script -Path .\NameOfScript.ps1 -NuGetApiKey 'key' -Verbose

Log:
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Publish-Script" on target "Version '1.0.0' of script 'NameOfScript'".
Publish-PSArtifactUtility : Failed to publish script 'NameOfScript': 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:2875 char:17
+ ...               Publish-PSArtifactUtility -PSScriptInfo $PSScriptInfo `
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailedToPublishTheScript,Publish-PSArtifactUtility
```

Answer (score 0):

This seemed intermittent! Worked after restarting PS Session.